# Magento server under maintenance after install the extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, maintenance

I have installed the extension through Magento connect manager. After installing extension, my site is under maintenance. I have tried these things:

1. Clear Cache and Session
2. I will change the index.php file

I did not see the maintenance.flag file in **var folder**.

Anyone help me.

Comment: Maintenance.flag is not created in /var iit is created in the root directory (same one as index.php is in)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly remove maintenance.flag file formed at the root folder of your magento installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can found "maintenance.flag" file in Magento root directory instead "var" directory. First you remove maintenance.flag file then download the extension file and upload manually.